# Link-local 169.254.x.x address assigned at boot despite static IP on 20.04 LTS

Tags: networking, server, iptables, router, nat

I have been struggling to setup my Ubuntu machine as a simple 2-NICs router with NAT, trying to stick to most recent recommended methods, namely `netplan` for the NICs and `ufw` for firewall *and* for iptables. I finally managed to get it routing but I cannot understand why at boot the system assigns a link-local (169.254.x.x) address to my LAN NIC *in addition* to the static IP, as if it were making a DHCP request and not getting a response. After a `sudo netplan apply`, the 169.254.x.x address is gone.

I'm not sure this is causing any trouble to my network but I don't understand it and it bothers me :-). Any hints are highly appreciated!

Here is my network topology:

```
  ISP router            Ubuntu router          Win10 Client 
[           ]   [ wan1              lan1 ]   [             ]
[192.168.1.1]---[192.168.1.8  192.168.9.1]---[192.168.9.10 ]
[           ]   [           (169.254.x.x)]   [  (static)   ]
[           ]   [(dhcp)          (static)]   [             ]
```

For the time being I didn't setup any DHCP server nor DNS daemon on the Ubuntu machine (I intend to do that shortly).

Note that this machine was installed as a Ubuntu desktop (I regret it now) and that I enabled systemd-networkd and disabled NetworkManager via `systemctl unmask/enable/start systemd-networkd` and `systemctl stop/disable/mask NetworkManager`.

After reboot `lan1` gets assigned a `169.254.x.x` address:

```
> ~ ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: lan1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 50:3e:aa:12:aa:cb brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.9.1/24 brd 192.168.9.255 scope global lan1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 169.254.232.216/16 brd 169.254.255.255 scope global noprefixroute lan1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::523e:aaff:fe12:aacb/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wan1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether e0:69:95:e4:d5:e8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.8/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic wan1
       valid_lft 86239sec preferred_lft 86239sec
    inet6 fe80::e269:95ff:fee4:d5e8/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

```
> ~ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    203    0        0 wan1
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     202    0        0 lan1
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     203    0        0 wan1
192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    100    0        0 wan1
192.168.9.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 lan1
```

After a manual re-apply of netplan with `sudo netplan apply` the `169.254.x.x` address is gone.

```
> ~ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    203    0        0 wan1
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     203    0        0 wan1
192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    100    0        0 wan1
192.168.9.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 lan1
```

Some details about my setup :

**/etc/netplan/01-router-all.yaml**

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd

  ethernets:
    wan1:
      match:
        macaddress: "e0:69:95:e4:d5:e8"
      set-name: wan1
      dhcp4: true
      accept-ra: false

    lan1:
      match:
        macaddress: "50:3e:aa:12:aa:cb"
      set-name: lan1
      dhcp4: false
      dhcp6: false
      addresses: [192.168.9.1/24]
      nameservers:
        addresses: [9.9.9.9, 1.1.1.1]
        search: []
     optional: true 
     accept-ra: false
```

**/etc/ufw/before.rules**

```
# rules.before
#
# Rules that should be run before the ufw command line added rules. Custom
# rules should be added to one of these chains:
#   ufw-before-input
#   ufw-before-output
#   ufw-before-forward
#

# NAT table rules
*nat
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]

# Forward traffic from lan1 to wan1
-A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.9.0/24 -o wan1 -j MASQUERADE

# don't delete the 'COMMIT' line or these nat table rules won't
# be processed
COMMIT

# Don't delete these required lines, otherwise there will be errors
*filter
:ufw-before-input - [0:0]
:ufw-before-output - [0:0]
:ufw-before-forward - [0:0]
:ufw-not-local - [0:0]
# End required lines

-A ufw-before-forward -i lan1 -o wan1 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-forward -i wan1 -o lan1 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

[rest of file unchanged]
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the problem was in `/etc/dhcpcd.conf`.

When moving from `NetworkManager` to `systemd-networkd`, I had commented the end of that file containing the name of the interfaces (as far as I remember it had been auto-populated with the NetWork Manager changes I made through `nmtui` when I had tried two static IPs).

I suspect that the DHCP client (needed for the wan `eno1` NIC) tried to assign an address to the lan NIC as well as it didn't know it was static (since I didn't say-so in `dhcpcd.conf`), and without a response it assigned a `169.254.x.x` address. It works now and I only have a static address after adding back the 2 lines at the end of `/etc/dhcpcd.conf`:

```
interface enp1s0
   static ip_address=192.168.9.1/24
```

I think I would have saved hours of setup if I had installed Ubuntu server vs desktop, and not had to switch to `systemd-networkd`. But I learned a lot along the way.

**Note**: since I posted my question I have setup a DHCP server (`isc-dhcp-server`) and to get it working I have been forced to remove the `lan1` alias, hence I moved back to using `enp1s0` (vs. `lan1` used in the question above).

Working `/etc/dhcpcd.conf`:

```
# A sample configuration for dhcpcd.
# See dhcpcd.conf(5) for details.

# Allow users of this group to interact with dhcpcd via the control socket.
#controlgroup wheel

# Inform the DHCP server of our hostname for DDNS.
hostname

# Use the hardware address of the interface for the Client ID.
#clientid
# or
# Use the same DUID + IAID as set in DHCPv6 for DHCPv4 ClientID as per RFC4361.
# Some non-RFC compliant DHCP servers do not reply with this set.
# In this case, comment out duid and enable clientid above.
duid

# Persist interface configuration when dhcpcd exits.
persistent

# Rapid commit support.
# Safe to enable by default because it requires the equivalent option set
# on the server to actually work.
option rapid_commit

# A list of options to request from the DHCP server.
option domain_name_servers, domain_name, domain_search, host_name
option classless_static_routes
# Respect the network MTU. This is applied to DHCP routes.
option interface_mtu

# Most distributions have NTP support.
option ntp_servers

# A ServerID is required by RFC2131.
require dhcp_server_identifier

noipv6rs
noipv6

# Generate SLAAC address using the Hardware Address of the interface
#slaac hwaddr
# OR generate Stable Private IPv6 Addresses based from the DUID

# mc 2020-07-18 commented below
#slaac private
interface enp1s0
        static ip_address=192.168.9.1/24
        #static routers=192.168.1.1
        #static domain_name_servers=9.9.9.9
#interface eno1
#        static ip_address=192.168.1.111/24
#        static routers=192.168.1.1
#        static domain_name_servers=9.9.9.9 149.112.112.112
```